# Как сделать на канвасе плавное перемещение объекта на позицию?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Как сделать на канвасе плавное перемещение объекта на позицию? вот код который я пробовал:

```
    function spawnCactus() {
        if (canvas.getContext) {
            cactusSpawned = true;
            curCactusXPosition = 800;
            while (true) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                curCactusXPosition = curCactusXPosition - 1;
                ctx.fillRect(10, curPlayerYPosition, 50, 100);
                ctx.fillRect(curCactusXPosition, 199, 50, 100);
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Молодец. И что дальше?)

Comment: Я не понимаю про что вы?

Comment: ..А про что *вы*?

Comment: Посмотрите справку о том [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и в т.ч. о том, [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  . Сейчас это что-то ни о чём-то

Comment: @MrYar, вы сами то поняли, что написали в коде?) У вас бесконечный цикл на уменьшение переменной curCactusXPosition. И curPlayerYPosition вообще не известна. Причем даже если вы ограничитесь проверкой на curCactusXPosition < 0. Ваш скрипт отработает так быстро, что вы не заметите никакого движения, нужно ставить какой-то sleep. Возможно стоит вызывать spawnCactus каждую секунду, передавать в него текущую координату curCactusXPosition и выкинуть цикл на мороз.

Answer (score 0):

У вас бесконечный цикл в котором бесконечно будет уменьшаться переменная + бесконечный цикл, который повесит весь скрипт.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

Ваш код:

```
let curPlayerYPosition = 10;

function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(curPlayerYPosition, 10, 50, 100);    
    curPlayerYPosition = curPlayerYPosition + 10;
}

setInterval(function() {
  draw();
}, 1000);
```